# Where are the GCP Firewall logs?

Tags: firewall, cloud, gcp

It's a little tricky to find GCP Firewall logs the first time you look for them.  Where are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following hyperlink for [gcp cloud Logs Explorer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query)

Example of how to filter traffic logs:

- This example looks for TCP traffic to 192.0.2.4:

```
jsonPayload.connection.dest_ip="192.0.2.4" AND jsonPayload.connection.protocol="6"
```